# A very strange issue when setting backgroundImage in flex mxml

Tags: flex3, mxml

This works:

```
<monitor:MonitorDisplay backgroundImage="http://domain.name/logo.png"/>
```

this doesn't work:

```
public var log_img:Class;
[source="http://domain.name/logo.jpg"]
```

...

```
<monitor:MonitorDisplay backgroundImage="{ log_img }"/>
```

Are the above 2 essentially the same?

Comment: Your syntax on the Class variable is wonky: it won't even compile on my system.  To declare an embedded image as a class variable, you need the `[Embed(source="...")]` tag *before* the variable declaration.

Comment: I don't want to embed it into the swf,but load it at run time.

Comment: Good to know: if you want to load it at runtime, see here: http://ntt.cc/2008/03/09/tips-three-ways-to-load-an-image-file-in-flex.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what a monitor:MonitorDisplay is, but it seems to me as if it's backgroundImage property probably expects an image class of some variety, not just `class`. I'd look at the definition for MonitorDisplay and see what the type is for backgroundImage.

Comment: The type should be OK because it also works if I change `[source="http://domain.name/logo.jpg"]` to `Embed([source="http://domain.name/logo.jpg"])`,but I don't want to embed it.